# Seo Problems in My meta Discription

Tags: plugins, shortcode, seo

Hi there guys i wanted to know how to fix this thing that is messing up with my SEO Meta description 
This is my homepage
[image: This is my homepage]

Comment: This forum is for Wordpress development, not SEO or Third Party plugin support.

Comment: so where should i have to post this

Comment: TBH -- Depends on what you're after. Are you looking for plugin support? If so, the support contact of the plugin you're using. General SEO guidelines? You can try the Webmasters SE site or Google. You're also not going to get very good support posting an image of your page. Finally, from this view there's no content on your page. You'll need to work on content before your SEO will even be a factor.

Comment: i am using newspaper theme it has so much content but using visual composer and i don't know what to do, so meta description could actually know that there is stuff

Comment: i just want to get my seo right

Comment: Well, then I suggest you start [here](https://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo/how-search-engines-operate) and continue moving on with [learning](https://www.google.com/search?q=getting+started+with+SEO) instead of trying to get others to fix it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing there is the shortcodes for your theme. You are likely using a theme builder which is why there are so many shortcodes. In the back-end, they will show as they are not being executed until they hit the front-end.

[You can see how shortcodes work with explanations here.](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/wordpress-shortcodes-complete-guide/)

In reality, they won't actually show up in search engines as by the time the search engine sees that page, the shortcodes will have executed and returned code/content.

If you are really worried about it, what you can do is manually override that description by putting some content into the "Meta Description" box.

Comment: i think that will do thank you, will tell you when i am done

Comment: It worked @steeve

Comment: Great. Ignore the others RE: Not being WordPress. This crosses over SEO with WordPress as it's a WordPress specific issue.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the correct answer if it was so.